# How to determine an end of TFrame resize through WM_NCHitTest

Tags: delphi

I use this code to resize TFrame when mouse is at the bottom-right corner:

```
TFrQuery = class(TFrame)
...

procedure TFrQuery.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
var P: TPoint;
begin
  P := ScreenToClient(Message.Pos);
  if (P.X >= (Width - 5)) and (P.Y >= (Height - 5)) then
    Message.Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

After resize is finished I need to realign the rest controls according to a new size of TFrame.

An OnResize event is not appropriate, because is hangs up everything.

How to find out that the TFrame resizing is over?

Or in other words (to help others in searching): how to define the OnAfterResize event for the TFrame, when the resize is made through WM_NCHitTest?

Comment: Why is `OnResize` not appropriate? In any case, look at the `WM_SIZING`, `WM_SIZE`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, and `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, well - imagine there are several descendants of TFrame - each is about to resize. If I resize the first one - it'll cause realign for the rest TFrames. I suppose some flags might solve the problem, but it seems to be not so elegant. I will try your advice and report

Comment: If you need to take multiple frame objects into account, then you will have to use a timer.  On the first resize of any frame, start the timer.  On subsequent resizes of any frame, restart the timer.  When the timer finally elapses, stop the timer and do something as needed.

Comment: On the other hand, why are you resizing the frame's controls manually at all, instead of using the `Align` and `Anchors` properties to let the controls resize themselves automatically for you?

Comment: Use Anchors and a GridPanel

Comment: Is it impossible somehow to catch `WM_LBUTTONUP`? Because the rest WMs don't do the work.  I have to resize manually as soon as there are at least two ways of control-alignment: vertical (one column list) and horizontal (multi columnt list). In the last case I need sometimes to expand some items manually both directions. Whilst in the first case - I want to expand only vertically. Is it impossible to solve without timers?

Comment: Actually I got this dilemma - I need to know that only the current `TFrame` was resized manually, because the others might be resized accordingly and there shoudn't be any propagation of realignment on the rest `TFrame`s.

Comment: I've got an answer and have posted it below. Please feel free to comment and make other suggestions. And thanks for ideas.

Comment: WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE and WM_EXITSIZEMOVE are your friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for now I got this two results with thanks to @RemuLebeau.

**First** and less elegant: with a `TTimer` (ResizeTimer) on the Form, which is being re-enabled each time an `OnResize` in an appropriate `TFrame` is being fired. To ensure that current `TFrame` is being manually resized you have to add a flag `FIsResizing`:

```
TFrQuery = class(TFrame)
  FIsResizing: boolean;
  Index: integer; //is assigned in run-time on adding
...

procedure TFrQuery.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
var
  P: TPoint;
begin
  P := ScreenToClient(Message.Pos);
  if (P.X >= (Width - 5)) and (P.Y >= (Height - 5)) then
  begin
    Message.Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
    FIsResizing := boolean; //indicates manual resizing
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TFrQuery.FrameResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FIsResizing then
  begin
    PResizeTimer.Tag := Index; //a pointer to a ResizeTimer on the Form
    PResizeTimer.Enabled := false;  //when ResizeTimer fires it simply
    PResizeTimer.Enabled := true;   //adjusts what needs to be adjusted 
    FIsResizing := false;
  end;
end;
...

unit Form1;
...
Procedure TForm1.ResizeTimerTimer(Sender: TObject)
begin
  ResizeTimer.Enabled := false;
  AdjustFrames(ResizeTimer.Tag);
end;
```

**Second** and more simple: no need of timer. You just need to track `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` message like this:

```
TFrQuery = class(TFrame)
  Index: integer; //is assigned in run-time on adding  
  FAdjustProc: TProc<Integer>; //Pointer to adjust method with Index
  procedure WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage); message WM_EXITSIZEMOVE;
...

procedure TFrQuery.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
var
  P: TPoint;
begin
  P := ScreenToClient(Message.Pos);
  if (P.X >= (Width - 5)) and (P.Y >= (Height - 5)) then
    Message.Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TFrQuery.WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  FAdjustProc(Index); 
  inherited;
end;
```

And no need of `OnResize` event or a flag `FIsResizing` at all. Each time you release mouse button an `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` occurs and fires valid method with a valid index of current `TFrame` element.

Main difference between them - is response either each `ResizeTimer.Interval` milliseconds or once - on mouse button release.

Any ideas are welcome!